# Install web server on my NAS

Tags: webserver, ftp, nas

I've bought some months ago a LaCie 1TB NAS, that works fine for home use.
However, I'd like to have a bit more control over it, and install at least  Web Server, so that I can host some PHP pages...

And I'd also like that data can be accessed from outside by FTP and SSH.

Do you know the simplest way to do it ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on what NAS you have, but looking at the standard consumer NASs that Lacie do, I can't see any that have a built in webserver that is capable of what you want to do.

Many support FTP and if you want to enable this for others to access your files, you simply need to forward FTP ports on your router to be forwarded to the IP of the NAS. Others will then be able to connect to your NAS by typing ftp://your_outside_ip - or by using the ip with your favourite FTP browser.

As for the webserver part, you can always install a webserver on another machine and use the NAS as the file store, but I do not think you will want to do that. If you do, again, you will simply need to forward HTTP/Port 80 from the router to the webserver.

Comment: I think you meant "ftp://your_outside_ip". Port forwarding can do a lot, but it can't magically change protocols.

Comment: @Hello71 Argh! It is past 1:00 AM, too tired to be doing this! +1 to you, -1 to me!!

Comment: thanks for your answer... indeed, my NAS support FTP, but don't have a built-in browser...
however, is there really no way to take the complete control of the NAS (like find the superuser credentials) and install what I want (like a webserver) ?

Comment: @Rolf this really depends on what model you have - but on most, they simply are not powerful enough to run a web server.

Comment: I don't find the exact name, but it's a LaCie Internet Space 1TB...
I'd like to setup a webserver for a few pages, that are meant for a few people...

Answer (score 1):

*I have an Network Space drive, and the following applies to that. It might also work on an Internet Space.*

It *might* be possible, however it's going to be a tedious process, and the performance of the cheap LaCie NAS'es isn't that great.

The process involves opening the case, removing the hard drive, and hooking it up to your Linux pc. Then you'll have to do some software stuff. In the end you'll have a webserver with sub-par performance. I decided it wasn't worth my effort.

If you'd like to try, see: http://lacie.nas-central.org/wiki/Category:Network_Space

Answer (score 0):

This is the NAS I use for hosting websites.

https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/overview/DS214+

Not cheap, but you get what you pay for and its great equipment.

Comment: They're not asking for a new NAS, they want to install web server software *on* their current NAS solution.